# How to build for subset of architectures when building for release

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I currently build my Android native libraries for several targets but as a build speed improvement I would like to build a subset based on the optimization setting. I tried something like this in the Application.mk but it's not working:

```
APP_MODULES := a b c
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
        APP_ABI := armeabi x86
else
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),release)
   APP_ABI  := armeabi-v7a
endif
endif
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

It the APP_OPTIM even set in this file? Or do I need to use an other variable like 'APP_DEBUG' or isn't this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can use the 'APP_DEBUG' boolean in your 'Application.mk' like this:

```
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),true)
APP_ABI := armeabi
else
ifeq ($(APP_DEBUG),false)
APP_ABI := x86 armeabi-v7a
else
# for cleaning all
APP_ABI := x86 armeabi-v7a armeabi
endif
endif
```

Hopefully I can help someone with this info.